# How do I check to see if any part of a string[] contains any part of another string[]?

Tags: c#, .net

This was the code I attempted to use:

```
if (results.Contains<string>(split.Any<string>) {

}
```

I really need this for a program I'm writing

Comment: Isn't this the same as asking whether any character is present in both strings?

Comment: That is why I needed another piece of code

Answer (score 7):

```
if (result.Intersect(split).Any())
```